# having trouble with sort error in the string

Tags: python, attributes

```
import string

def scaryDict(filename1, filename2):
    s= filename1
    Infile=open(filename1,'r')
    OF = open(filename2, 'w')
    for line in Infile:
        Infile= s.lower()
        Infile= s.replace('-',' ')
        Infile= s.split()
        Infile= s.sort()
        scaryWords=[]
        for word in filename1:
            if len(word)>2:
                scaryWords.append(word)
    outfile.write(scaryWords)
    Infile.close()
    OF.close()
    print(scaryWords)
scaryDict('frankenstein.txt', 'scarydict.txt')
```

when i run the program i get the message that string doesn't have the atrribute as sort something like that####

Comment: That sounds about right.  I don't think strings have a `.sort()` method.  You probably don't want to be overwritting your `Infile` variable like that either.

Comment: so you mean that i dont need s.sort() in my code???

Comment: sort list, not string

Comment: so i an removing the .sort from my code that is fine

Comment: and can you guys give this question up so i have some reputition

Comment: It appears there are multiple problems with this piece of code.  It would be helpful if you describe what you are trying to do, then someone may be able to point you in the right direction.